# Bootstrap Tooltip in Span Tag (parent) of Img tag (child) failing to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I currently have an unordered list, within it is multiple list items which contain images which I would like to have a tooltip popup above them upon hovering over the image. I was told to place a span tag around them and it should work but I'm only seeing a normal tooltip at the moment. Code Below:

```
<ul class="list-inline dev-icons">
      <li class="list-inline-item">
        <span class="d-inline-block" tabindex="0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto top" title="Microsoft Word">
          <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/ms-word.png">
        </span>
      </li>
      <li class="list-inline-item">
        <span class="d-inline-block" tabindex="0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto top" title="Microsoft Excel">
          <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/ms-excel.png">
        </span>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Edit: Error message from console.log -

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
>       at lt (popper.js:629)
>       at Object.onLoad (popper.js:1134)
>       at popper.js:2342
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at new t (popper.js:2340)
>       at s.T.show (tooltip.js:287)
>       at s.T._enter (tooltip.js:548)
>       at HTMLSpanElement. (tooltip.js:480)
>       at HTMLSpanElement.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at HTMLSpanElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)

My js packages are placed as so (with sort.js containing my code for Jquery data-target function):

```
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
  <script src="js/resume.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/sort.js"></script>
```

Comment: what is the plugin you are using ?

Comment: popper? i'm receiving a few errors at the moment

Comment: added the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `tooltip()` function to get results,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<ul class="list-inline dev-icons">
      <li class="list-inline-item">
        <span class="d-inline-block" tabindex="0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto top" title="Microsoft Word">
          <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/ms-word.png"/>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li class="list-inline-item">
        <span class="d-inline-block" tabindex="0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto top" title="Microsoft Excel">
          <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/ms-excel.png"/>
        </span>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I seem to be getting error messages? is it because I have placed popper.min.js into my vendor folder?

Comment: no worries. Hope you have solved. Happy coding mate. Cheers!

Comment: I'm receiving errors posted in the yellow blockcode at the top, if you could take a look. I think it's to do with my file inclusion

Comment: it is happening due to order of the `js` references. seems `indexOf` cannot read which is a `jQuery` function. may be add latest version of a jquery.

Comment: you think i need to replace the vendor package (jQuery) with a newer version?

Answer (score 0):

Answered: data-placement="auto top" does not work for some reason but data-placement="top" did!